# After run this python code couldn't passed all the test cases

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to solve hackerrank linear algebra problem. Here is the Task:

> > You are given a square matrix  with dimensions X. Your task is to find
> > the determinant. Note: Round the answer to 2 places after the decimal. 
> > The first line contains the integer N . The next N lines contains
> > the N space separated elements of array A.

Here is my code

```
import numpy
i = int(input())
l = []

while i > 0:

    a,b = map(float, input().split())
    l.append([a,b])
    # l.append([a])
    i = i - 1

result = numpy.linalg.det(l)
print(round(result,2))
```

after run this it failed to pass this test case:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 2 1
```

output: 6.0

for this test case user takes 3 variable but in my code i took 2 variable that's why i can't pass this test case. But how can i ensure in my code that no matter how many variable user took at the end it will show the output and saved in the list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change your code so as it accepts more than 2 numbers on a line:

```
i = int(input())
l = []

while i > 0:
    row = list(map(float, input().split()))
    l.append(row)
    i = i - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i couldn't understand that. i need two dimensional array

Comment: @IftekharChowdhury yes, each row is a `1D` array, and `l` is an array of `1D` arrays, i.e. a `2D` array.